# Replacement for toggle() multiple div sets

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, hide, show

I've been working on this for a while and thought I'd like to get some expert advice.
I have 4 divs on a page labelled sun-sun3. When each of the divs is clicked a corresponding div (suninfo-suninfo3) will appear and when clicked again will disappear. While one of the info divs is open the others will always  be closed.

Here is the html

```
<div class="dot sun">
</div>
<div class="info suninfo">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun1">
</div>
<div class="info suninfo1">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun2">
</div>
<div class="info suninfo2">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun3">
</div>
<div class="info suninfo3">Some Content</div>
```

The CSS is styled so that the sun divs use pulse which works fine and the suninfo divs appear in various locations around the page. All works perfectly.

The following Javascript also works fine, however it is using toggle() which I would like to replace. My code is also quite long.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".sun").click(function(){
   $(".suninfo").toggle();
   $(".suninfo1,.suninfo2,.suninfo3").hide();
  });
  $(".sun1").click(function(){
    $(".suninfo1").toggle();
    $(".suninfo,.suninfo2,.suninfo3").hide();
  });
  $(".sun2").click(function(){
    $(".suninfo2").toggle();
    $(".suninfo,.suninfo1,.suninfo3").hide();
  });
  $(".sun3").click(function(){
    $(".suninfo3").toggle();
    $(".suninfo,.suninfo1,.suninfo2").hide();
  });
});
```

As you can see, there isn't much to it and it does work, but I'd rather not use toggle()

Cheers

Comment: Can you post a demo, try http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging jQueryUI for this -- as it provides this functionality out of the box.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

In addition it will not require you to modify your script if you decide to later add divs for sun4, sun5, and/or sun6, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more simple according to you structure:

```
$(".dot").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
       $(this).next().toggle();
       $(".info").not($(this.next())).hide();
    })
})
```

Why don`t you like toggle?
To manually control it you can:

```
$(element).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},1500) //([animation, params, time])
$(element).show('slide')
```

if using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use start with jquery selector in this case but need to rename 'suninfo' class name because 'sun' and 'suninfo' class names starts with 'sun' word, so it will be difficult to use start with jquery selector. Also selector class name should be first while writing in div

like if we are using `$("[class^='suninfo']")` then `suninfo` should be first call in `<div class="suninfo info">`.

Please see below jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[class^='sun']").click(function(){
      var nextElement = $(this).next();
      $(nextElement).toggle();
      $("[class^='infoSun']").not($(nextElement)).hide();
});
```

here rename your `suninfo` class to `infoSun` and call it at first place like below

```
<div class="dot sun">
</div>
<div class="infoSun info">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun1">
</div>
<div class="infoSun1 info">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun2">
</div>
<div class="infoSun2 info">Some Content</div>
<div class="dot sun3">
</div>
<div class="infoSun3 info">Some Content</div>
```

Please see [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for more information on start with selector in JQuery